# How to Avoid re-rendering of the screens in a tabNavigator once I make a setState of a screenProps?

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-navigation, react-native-firebase

I am implementing push notifications in a react native project, where from the parent component of the application I need to pass parameters through the reactNavigation screenProps for a BottomTabNavigator. Once I receive a notification, and I change the status to update the parameter that will indicate to the child components that must be updated, a complete re-rendering of the application is made. 
This is my code:

```
class AppLayout extends Component {
  state = {
    updatePushNotifications: false
  }

  handleActivatePushNotifications = () => {
    this.handlePushNotificationMessageListener();
  }

  handlePushNotificationMessageListener = async () => {
   this.notificationListener = firebase.notifications().onNotification((notification) => {
     const { title, body } = notification;
     console.log(notification);
     console.log('notificationListener');

     //SETSTATE FOR UPDATE CALLS IN CHILD COMPONENTS
     this.setState({
       updatePushNotifications: true
     });

     this.showAlert(title, body);
   });
  }

  showAlert = (title, message) => {
     Alert.alert(
      title,
      message,
      [
       {text: 'OK', onPress: () => console.log('OK Pressed')},
      ],
      {cancelable: false},
     );
  }

  // The entire navigation component is re-rendered once the setState is executed
  render () {
    return (
      <Layout
        screenProps={{
          updatePushNotifications: this.state.updatePushNotifications
        }}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

**How can I prevent a re-render of the application when I update any of the parameters that I am passing through the screenProps?**

Thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 0):

If you use state in your render method, it always re-render your app with state changes. You can define a variable in class and update it. Then pass it to prop. But be careful, because you can't see changes if you don't make forceUpdate.